# Can I install Ubuntu on a Lenovo E520-1143?

Tags: installation, lenovo

I have a Lenovo E520-1143.

At the moment I have Windows 7 Professional 64bit installed. Is it possible to install Ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop? If I installed Ubuntu 11.10 will the devices such as Audio,Display, Bluetooth, LAN, wan, fingerprint, etc. works for me?

If I install Ubuntu will it detected all devices?

Comment: You may find this useful: ['E520' on Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/?desktops=on&laptops=on&stars=1&popularity=any&term=E520)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu for the first time, you are advised to experience Ubuntu through Live CD or Bootable USB disks. You can download and create these from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) website. Insert the CD/USB and boot from it. By default certain codecs such as for video, audio flash etc are not shipped with Ubuntu. Still you can experience all other applications and everything. Take it from me, if you are pretty satisfied in overall experience from Live CD/USB, you do not need to bother about audio and video. If you want to install Ubuntu, you can do it along with the Current Windows 7. It is not a hectic thing to install Ubuntu since it is designed in such a way that a basic computer literate can install Ubuntu. Follow on screen instructions and you can make it. Once installation is complete, open Ubuntu software centre and serach for Ubuntu Restricted extras. It is around 100 MB file containing codec for audio video flash java etc. For better video experience you can even try VLC player. That's it. This all you need to run a fully loaded Ubuntu on your lap/desktop.

Please revert for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

About 2 months ago I purchased a Lenovo E420 with the sole intention of using it as my Ubuntu machine (well, dual-booted, really). It is very nearly identical to the E520 except for size.

I booted from my Live CD,partitioned 75% of my HD to be used for Ubuntu 11.11, and voila; the installation was a breeze. Everything works wonderfully. If anything, be sure you look into the usual tweaks and software to ensure you get decent battery life (e.g. laptop-mode / powertop). Compared to running Win7, my Ubuntu gets about 70% battery life when compared.

All of my hardware was recognized. The only thing I can't vouche for here would be the fingerprint reader, because my E420 doesn't have one.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try first the live cd. Thats a first indication how your hardware deals with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 (64bit) on my lenovo G560 (Intel Core i3, 3GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics, 350 GB Hard disk) I didn't face any problem related to any hardware detection. Ubuntu detected all the hardware. I don't have figure print hardware on my system, So not sure about that. Many people faced problems related to WiFi connectivity on some Lenovo systems but there are solutions for that also. Also you can try it with Ubuntu Live CD on your system and see how things go.